# how to start rails thin server server with god

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, god

```
RAILS_ROOT = File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__))

God.watch do |w|
  pid_file = File.join(RAILS_ROOT, "tmp/pids/server.pid")

  w.name = "thin"
  w.interval = 60.seconds
  w.start = "rails server -e production"
  w.stop = "kill -s QUIT $(cat #{pid_file})"
  w.restart = "kill -s HUP $(cat #{pid_file})"
  w.start_grace = 20.seconds
  w.restart_grace = 20.seconds
  w.pid_file = pid_file

  w.behavior(:clean_pid_file)

  # When to start?
  w.start_if do |start|
    start.condition(:process_running) do |c|
      # We want to check if deamon is running every ten seconds
      # and start it if itsn't running
      c.interval = 10.seconds
      c.running = false
    end
  end
```

i tried  w.start = "rails server -e production" but its not working it says

INFO: thin moved 'up' to 'up'
I [2014-05-02 23:37:09]  INFO: thin [trigger] process is not running (ProcessRunning)
I [2014-05-02 23:37:09]  INFO: thin move 'up' to 'start'

Comment: surendar - Can you join chat room?

Answer (score 0):

create a rake task for thin

```
namespace :server do
  desc "start thin server"
  task start: :environment do
    puts Rails.root
     `cd #{Rails.root}`
     str  = "rails s -e production"
     puts "Starting server" 
     `#{str}`
  end
end
```

and start it like this

w.start   = "cd #{RAILS_ROOT} && rake server:start"

if u used exec rails s -e prodution then the god daemon will be exited and u get server unavailbale error. so u need a rake task for it